# findAny orElse after filter

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I'm using Stream filter `findAny.orElse`, but it's not working as I expect, so I presume I'm not understanding how really works.
Here my code

```
return Stream.of(getObjectAttributeValue(product, matchCriteria.getFieldName()))
             .map(o -> isIngredientRestricted(matchCriteria, (List<String>) o))
             .filter(Boolean::valueOf)
             .findAny().orElse(isCommercialHierarchyInfoRestricted(product, matchCriteria));
```

Basically what I was expecting was that if the first map emit a Boolean false, then it will be filter so then the findAny would not find any optional, so the orElse would be invoked. But even having a true in the filter the isCommercialHierarchyInfoRestricted is invoked.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `orElse` is invoked or `isCommercialHierarchyInfoRestricted` is invoked?

Comment: `.map(…).filter(Boolean::valueOf)` looks nonsensical. Why not just `.filter(…)` in the first place, i.e. `.filter(o -> isIngredientRestricted(matchCriteria, (List<String>) o))`?

Comment: @zeroflagL isCommercialHierarchyInfoRestricted is invoked. Maybe the main problem here, is that I should not use Stream

Comment: Oh, I see. You want the `boolean` result as the overall result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Tagir explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588504/2711488), using `orElse(expression)` always causes the evaluation of `expression` before invoking the method `orElse` and you have to use `orElseGet(() -> expression)` instead to defer the evaluation of the expression.

However, this is an unnecessary use of the `Stream` API. If you want to evaluate a single item, you don’t need to create a single-element stream just to call `findAny` afterwards. You can create an `Optional` in the first place:

```
return Optional.of(getObjectAttributeValue(product, matchCriteria.getFieldName()))
     .map(o -> isIngredientRestricted(matchCriteria, (List<String>)o))
     .filter(b -> b)
     .orElseGet(() -> isCommercialHierarchyInfoRestricted(product, matchCriteria));
```

However, even that is an unnecessary complication compared to the equivalent ordinary Java language construct:

```
return isIngredientRestricted(matchCriteria,
           (List<String>)getObjectAttributeValue(product, matchCriteria.getFieldName()))
  ||  isCommercialHierarchyInfoRestricted(product, matchCriteria);
```

This does exactly the same without the need for additional APIs nor lambda expressions. The `||` operator also guarantees that the second expression won’t get evaluated, if the first one evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Yep, sometimes we want use functional programing more that we need. I revert as I had before without use Stream.

Answer (score 14):

You actually need to use [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
.findAny().orElseGet(() -> isCommercialHierarchyInfoRestricted(product, matchCriteria));
```

In Java method argument is always evaluated prior to method call even if it's unnecessary inside the method, so you cannot avoid evaluating the `orElse` argument. That's why `orElseGet` exists: its argument is the function and the function can be not executed at all when it's not necessary.